# Mapbox UI classes cannot be imported

Tags: android, android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am following this tutorial: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-navigation-sdk/

No matter what I do these packages cannot be imported.

```
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncherOptions;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.route.NavigationMapRoute;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncher;
```

This is the error I get:
**package com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5 does not exist**

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: And yes these packages actually do exist when you google them. I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the tutorial is missing about one attribute that has to be imported in the gradle. So,

Aside from adding:

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.42.6'
```

You must add this too:

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.42.6'
```

Comment: what about `PlaceAutocompleteOptions`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77166330/7767664